# Ionic Live Reload on emulator or actual device doesn't work

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic3 emulate option for android is causing me some issues, i tried to launch the project using Livereload on an emulator and also an actual device using the following code

```
ionic cordova run android --device -l --debug --address 1**.1**.*.**
```

Its showing me the following output in console:-

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 1**.1**.*.** --port 8100 --
livereload-port 35729
--dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser --iscordovaserve --platform android --target cordova - Ctrl+C
to cancel
[20:06:10]  watch started ...
[20:06:10]  build dev started ...
```

then the build stops and the process finishes without showing any error.
Is there any extra options need to be given or something to with my ports ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same command but without the `--address` flag. I am then prompted to select from a list of IPs. The first one on the list is always the correct one. It works every time!